# Is it possible to dockerise Javafx application. Can I run image file in browser?

Tags: docker, javafx-8

I have built desktop application in JavaFX. I am trying to create image using docker. So I can run image file in browser. Is it possible?

If it is possible so please help me, How to create docker file for JavaFX application.

Comment: What do you mean by `run image file in browser`? You don't run docker images in a browser.

Comment: I mean, how to expose in browser?